# ForEach not updating when deleting from ActionSheet

Tags: swiftui

I have an app that has a view with a for each with some child views. On the child view, I have a delete button that triggers a completion handler that shows an ActionSheet on the parent view that deletes the corresponding child, except the for each is not updating (keeps showing the original items).

The weird thing is that if I delete it directly in the completion handler (no ActionSheet), it works fine, but when I delete it from the ActionSheet, it doesn't work. Also, I have another action sheet that deletes an entire project, and that works fine.

I have an optional state property to store the item to delete (sent back by the completion handler).

The ForEach (on parent):

```swift
ForEach(viewModel.project.counters.indices, id: \.self) { i in
   AddEditCounterView(
       viewModel: AddEditCounterViewModel(
           counter: viewModel.project.counters[i],
           projectCount: viewModel.project.counters.count,
           saveHandler: { counter in viewModel.updateCounter(counter: counter) },
           deleteHandler: { counterToDelete in
               self.counterToDelete = counterToDelete
               activeSheet = .deleteCounter
//             viewModel.deleteCounter(counterToDelete)  // If I delete directly here, it works
           }
           ),
           isNew: false,
           isValid: $countersValidationResult[i],
           doValidation: $performValidateCounters
       )
}
```

The Button (on child):

```swift
Button(action: {
    viewModel.deleteHandler(viewModel.counter)
}, label: {
    Text(NSLocalizedString("Delete Counter", comment: "button label"))
})
```

The ActionSheet (on parent):

```swift
.actionSheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
    switch item {
    case .deleteProject:
        return ActionSheet(title: Text(NSLocalizedString(String.localizedStringWithFormat("Delete %@", viewModel.project.name), comment: "alert title")), message: Text(NSLocalizedString("Deleting a project can't be undone", comment: "Deleting alert message")), buttons: [
            .destructive(Text(NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment: "Button label"))) {
                viewModel.deleteHandler(viewModel.project.id)  // This works fine
            },
            .cancel()
        ])
    case .deleteCounter: // This is where the problem happens
        return ActionSheet(title: Text(NSLocalizedString(String.localizedStringWithFormat("Delete %@", counterToDelete?.name ?? NSLocalizedString("Counter", comment: "Generic counter name")), comment: "alert title")), message: Text(NSLocalizedString("Deleting a counter can't be undone", comment: "Deleting alert message")), buttons: [
            .destructive(Text(NSLocalizedString("Delete", comment: "Button label"))) {
                if let c = counterToDelete {
                    print(viewModel.project.counters.count) // Prints, for example 3
                    viewModel.deleteCounter(counter: c)
                    print(viewModel.project.counters.count) // Prints one less than above, 2
                }
            },
            .cancel()
        ])
    }
}
```

I tried having just the one action sheet (to see if it was that having two was an issue) but makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I was hoping someone had encountered something similar, @loremipsum. I’ll try making a workable example.